# $\frac{2}{\lVert x \rVert^2} \langle x,u \rangle \langle x,v\rangle - \langle u, v\rangle \leq \lVert u \rVert \lVert v \rVert$?

Tags: inequality, vectors, proof-explanation, inner-products

In $\mathbb R^n$, $\frac{2}{\lVert x \rVert^2} \langle x,u \rangle \langle x,v\rangle - \langle u, v\rangle \leq \lVert u \rVert \lVert v \rVert$?

The book says the above inequality can be obtained by using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the bound $$\langle R(u), v \rangle \leq \lVert R(u) \rVert \lVert v \rVert \leq \lVert u \rVert \lVert v \rVert, $$ where $R(u)$ is the reflection point of the vector $u$. I don't see how to get the desired inequality from the hint.

Comment: What's $(x,v)$?

Comment: @ogogmad Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: Reflection of $v$ across a hyperplane orthogonal to $x$ through the origin would be $$v-2\frac{\left<v,x\right>}{\left<x,x\right>}x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\hat x = \frac{x}{|x|}$. Then
$$\begin{align}
2\langle \hat x, u\rangle\langle \hat x, v\rangle - \langle u, v\rangle &= \langle 2\hat x\langle \hat x,u\rangle-u,v\rangle \\
&= \langle R(u),v\rangle
\end{align}$$
because as N8tron said, $R(u)=2\hat x\langle \hat x,u\rangle-u$.

For completeness: $$\begin{align}
|R(u)|^2 &= |\hat x\langle \hat x,u\rangle+(\hat x\langle \hat x,u\rangle-u)|^2\\
&=\langle \hat x,u\rangle^2+|\hat x\langle \hat x,u\rangle-u|^2 \tag{Pythagoras's thm}\\
&=\langle \hat x,u\rangle^2+|u-\hat x\langle \hat x,u\rangle|^2\\
&= |\langle \hat x,u\rangle\hat x+u-\hat x\langle \hat x,u\rangle|^2 \tag{Pythagoras's thm}\\
&=|u|^2
\end{align}$$